# autocomplete showing self.element.propAttr error

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery ui Autocomplete.But it show error autocomplete showing `self.element.propAttr` error. 
this is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "persons.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function( xmlResponse ) {
            var data = $( "person", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                return {
                    value: $( "name", this ).text()

                };
            }).get();
            $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: 0

            });


        }

    });
```

I am using xml for response but that doesnot seem to be the problem it seems some function in javascript is deprecated.
Can anyone give me any solutions for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add this lines in front of your statement:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
 propAttr: $.fn.prop || $.fn.attr
});
```

Comment: I have solved this problem.thanks for the answer. web console was pointing towards `self.options.disabled|| self.element.propAttr("readOnly")` as error.this line in jquery.ui.autocomplete.js .I deleted that line altogether and voila!! it worked.May be that is not good practice but it worked.i will try your suggestion though..

Comment: @Narendra Chitrakar : Could you explain why/how this solves the problem and what the problem was in the first place?

Comment: Deleting the line will make it show for readonly or disabled inputs as well as inputs for which you can actually select a value, given answer does the trick, is their extra value to the extend? surely it could be jQuery.fn.propAttr = $.fn.prop || $.fn.attr;

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem when refactoring my javascript and found that the problem was I removed jquery.ui.core.js, and instead was using only jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js.

I created this file using the Download Builder at the Jquery UI website with everything checked. Correct me If I am wrong but jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js should have contained all the javascript necessary to run all the jquery ui addins (in this case autocomplete was failing).

Adding the reference back to jquery.ui.core.js fixed the bug.