# JQueryUI autocomplete is working locally and not on server. (MVC 4)

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

After hours of troubleshooting it appears the jqueryui autocomplete is not working on the server I'm deploying my application to, but it's working on my local machine.

I have tested Ajax calls and they are working fine. I'm able to get content, etc...

I'm able to use the datepicker from the ui controls, but not autocomplete.

To be sure, I used the code at the bottom of my question. This code works on my local but not on the server. I'm assuming the autocomplete is not loading properly.

If you are familiar with this issue, PLEASE help and let me know what's a good alternative.

The actual page I'm testing is http://StagKingAdmin.com

```
                        var availableTags = [
                        "ActionScript",
                        "AppleScript",
                        "Asp",
                        "BASIC",
                        "C",
                        "C++",
                        "Clojure",
                        "COBOL",
                        "ColdFusion",
                        "Erlang",
                        "Fortran",
                        "Groovy",
                        "Haskell",
                        "Java",
                        "JavaScript",
                        "Lisp",
                        "Perl",
                        "PHP",
                        "Python",
                        "Ruby",
                        "Scala",
                        "Scheme"
                        ];
                        $("input#searchterm").autocomplete({
                            source: availableTags
                        });
```

Comment: What versions of jQuery & jQueryUI are you using?

Comment: ui 1.10.2 and jquery 1.7.1

Comment: If you load them from a CDN (like [Microsoft's](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDN.ashx)) instead of locally, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the page on the server is taking longer to load than locally, so perhaps the DOM isn't fully loaded when `.autocomplete()` is called.

Is your autocomplete call wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` function? If not, it should be.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#searchterm").autocomplete({
       source: availableTags
    });
});
```

This will ensure the `input#searchterm` element is available when `.autocomplete()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

From what i saw in the given url, your problem is relevant to this [qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527933/autocomplete-showing-self-element-propattr-error),

Add the following script before the autocomplete setup

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
     propAttr: $.fn.prop || $.fn.attr
});
```

also add a `/` before relative urls like,

```
var autoCompleteUrl_Events = '/Events/Find/';
```

hope this helps.

Comment: The autocomplete is wrapped in the ready function and is working locally but not on the server. Also, I'm using other jqueryui items like the datepicker. I will post the complete code for the page. It's not a lot.

Comment: Also some functionalities have been deprecated since jquery 1.7. You should use the latest if not possible the later version of jquery to work with latest version of jquery ui.

Comment: jQuery.fn.extend({
     propAttr: $.fn.prop || $.fn.attr
}); Got the results to show, but now the results at the top left of the screen. I'm going to replace my libraries and see what happens.

Comment: Yes i saw that, and if you use the latest jquery and ui version, i don't think you will need the tweak. Its only to make jquery ui work with earlier version like jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, was working locally and not working on remote server. 
When i stopped including autocomplete script at the bottom of the page and included it along with jquery inside the `<head>` then it started working.